# Sql Injection problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have HttpHandler page which I use to do some stuffs that includes the using of DB . I need to be able to prevent people from getting access to this file and to make sure that the info's path is my website and not another web page which using Processrequest to achieve this .

```
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {


    if (context.Request.Url.Authority.ToString() != HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority.ToString())
        return;
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    string str = context.Request.Form["recordsArray[]"].ToString();
    char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',', ';' };
    string[] arr = str.Split(delimiters);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
         Functions.Add(new tab(arr[i])); // insert records into table Tabs => int id, string name           
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're worried about sql injection, show us the code that actually talks to the db. Don't skip that part.

Comment: It appears that you are currently trying to compare if A != A in other words I would ( this is just a guess ) assume that HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority.ToString() is actually equal to context because of the "Current" ( context ).

Comment: @Ramhound : Hhh Yea youre right , futile attempt .

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent people having access to some resource normally you protect this resource with an authentication: you grant authorized users with username/password allowing you to distinguish them from unauthorized users.

An HTTP request can be forged and made to look exactly as if it was coming from your domain, while actually it doesn't. So the only way is to use some secret.

Comment: Yes but I have no specific users, its a news script.

Comment: @Israa Abd, well in this case you cannot distinguish between users of your web site and other users. There is no such notion of *users of my website* unless you provide them with some secret in order to identify them. As I said, anyone could forge an HTTP request.

Comment: Agreed, security of any type first requires authentication.  You need to think about how you plan to identify your users and then code around that concept.

Comment: I don't want any user or any guest to see the file. I just use it to insert data using ajax .

Comment: @Israa Abd, yes but AJAX means javascript and javascript means client and client means user. So at the end of the day it's the user that sends the request. So we are back to my first comment: you need to authenticate those users if you want to prevent anyone from sending HTTP requests to your site, it's as simple as that.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, 
If I declare a static Application value in global.asax e.g Application["X"] = "Y"; and asked about its value in the HttpHandler page before doing any thing, is that could help !?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov , what happen if I check the Context's UrlReferrer with my domain name ?

Comment: @Israa Abd, the url referrer can be faked so it is completely unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also something that handles SQL injection for you.

Linq to sql: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx

or for something a bit simpler, you could just use SQL parameters (with is what Linq to SQL uses):

(a short guide): http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/content/archive/2007/05/25/creating-sqlparameters-best-practices.aspx
or here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

I know this isn't a specifically a solution for you, but I hope that helps.